# Customers not receiving emails with attachments

Tags: email2case, send-email

We just implemented Email-to-Case and we are facing this issue in our Salesforce Production environment.

> When agents are replying to customers with email attachments, they emails are not being received by the customers.
>   We have not able to reproduce it in lower environments and everything was working in lower env from beginning - this was also tested thoroughly.
>
> There are no access or other errors that they are getting.
>   They are able to attach the attachments from their system to the email they are about to send but still the customers are not receiving emails.
>   There are no errors in Salesforce.
>   We still see the sent email with attachments.

Has anyone faced such an issue earlier / any possible resolutions?

Comment: Are you talking about replying with attachments that were in the customer's original response or attachments that agents are adding when they compose the reply? If the latter, where are they adding attachments from? Are they seeing the file attached in the email composition component?

Comment: I am talking about attachments that the agents add later while replying to the customer. They attach files from their desktop/ laptop. The files are attached to email and email is also sent successfully and they can see the sent email in email message related list too and attachment sent in attachment related list too.

Comment: this sounds unrelated to emailToCase, which routes inbound email messages and attachments.